# <p> text bleeding out of .input-group .form-control container but not in jsFiddle

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a strange situation here. The following Bootstrap3 based code looks fine in jsFiddle, but not when running anywhere else. As you can see from the links provided, the p text bleeds out of it's tag on my server, but looks fine in jsFiddle (both using bootstrap3).

Any idea what could be causing this? Thanks.

The code:

```
<form action="">
    <div class="row"><div class="col-sm-12">
        <h4>Step 1:</h4>
    </div></div>
    <div class="row"><div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <input type="checkbox">
                </span>
                <p class="form-control">Long description text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text...</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div></div>
</form>
```

Here it is on my server: http://leke.ydns.eu/ac2/

...and on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n2fole00/6JyFr/4/

**Edit:**
Here is a screenshot: [image]

Comment: it looks the same in chrome for me, which browser do you use?

Comment: I tested it in Chrome and Firefox with the same results. I'll add a screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seemed bootstrap was setting the .form-control to 34px. I just over wrote the class like so

```
.form-control {
    height: auto;
}
```

...and that took care of that.